# Why does the layout validation fail after switching to "developer" mode?

Tags: layout, developer-mode

Why do these exceptions appear just now? I can't switch back to "default" mode. What can I do?

Logs on frontend:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'htmlClass': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'content.home' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*'.
Line: 812

Element 'container', attribute 'htmlClass': 'content.home' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'htmlClassType'.
Line: 812


Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'container', attribute 'htmlClass': [facet 'pattern'] The value 'content.home' is not accepted by the pattern '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*(\s[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d\-_]*)*'.
Line: 812

Element 'container', attribute 'htmlClass': 'content.home' is not a valid value of the atomic type 'htmlClassType'.
Line: 812

#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php(115): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->_initDom('<layout xmlns:x...')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(111): Magento\Framework\Config\Dom->__construct('<layout xmlns:x...', Object(Magento\Framework\App\Arguments\ValidationState), Array, NULL, '/var/www/html/v...', '%message%\nLine:...')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(56): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Config/DomFactory.php(42): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('Magento\\Framewo...', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Update/Validator.php(125): Magento\Framework\Config\DomFactory->createDom(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(461): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Update\Validator->isValid('<layout xmlns:x...', 'layout_merged', false)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Model/Layout/Merge.php(442): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->_validateMergedLayout('LAYOUT_frontend...', '<body>\n   <refe...')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(86): Magento\Framework\View\Model\Layout\Merge->load()
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout/Builder.php(63): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->loadLayoutUpdates()
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(254): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Builder->build()
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(875): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->build()
#12 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(414): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Helper/Page.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getBlock('page_content_he...')
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Index/Index.php(43): Magento\Cms\Helper\Page->prepareResultPage(Object(Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor), 'artfurniture-1-...')
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Action/Action.php(107): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index->execute()
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Cms/Controller/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#20 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Cms\Controller\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#21 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#22 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#23 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-store/App/FrontController/Plugin/RequestPreprocessor.php(94): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#24 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Store\App\FrontController\Plugin\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#25 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(69): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#26 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#27 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#28 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#29 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#30 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#31 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#32 {main}
```

and on backend:

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 5

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 6

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 7

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 8


Exception #0 (LogicException): Could not create an acl object: Invalid Document 
Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 5

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 6

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 7

Element 'resource': The attribute 'title' is required but missing.
Line: 8

#0 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/Acl/Builder/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder->getAcl()
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth/Session.php(227): Magento\Framework\Acl\Builder\Proxy->getAcl()
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/Model/Auth.php(159): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Session->processLogin()
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth->login('admin', '123qweASD')
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callParent('login', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('admin', '123qweASD')
#6 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->___callPlugins('login', Array, Array)
#7 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(205): Magento\Backend\Model\Auth\Interceptor->login('admin', '123qweASD')
#8 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(157): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_performLogin(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(125): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->_processNotLoggedInUser(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#12 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Backend/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#13 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Backend\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#15 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#16 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#17 /var/www/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#18 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#19 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#20 /var/www/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#21 {main}
```

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to [official document](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-mode.html):

> You cannot currently change from either developer or production mode to default mode.

So to continue your development, you should use **developer mode** by the following command:

```
magento deploy:mode:set developer
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that. I can't figure it out why the layout worked fine in default mode, but after setting the developer one it broke. And what should I do to fix the exceptions